# Using IdentityServer4 with spa JS UI instead of ASP.NET Core MVC views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I recently built my IdentityServer4 as a api and a vueJs UI for the Login/Registration/Reset Password.

```
services.AddIdentityServer (options => {
          options.Discovery.ShowIdentityScopes = false;
          options.Discovery.ShowApiScopes = false;
          options.Discovery.ShowClaims = false;

          options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "http://authUI/Login" //vue UI
        })
```

The api is up and running and I can get to the login page.

However, after authentication, I'm getting a 404 error, because the returnUrl is resolving to the UI Url instead of the Identityserver api URL.

Is there a way to change the way the returnUrl are generated in IdentityServer4?

Comment: Add `RedirectUris` for that client.